# Will I lose the enhancements if I trade my robot?

Tags: one-must-fall-2097

I have an enhancement level 1 for Jaguar.

If I trade my robot for any of the robots available, what happens to the enhancements that I won for my robot? Do I have to win those again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you trade your robot, you will lose all of the enhancements on your current robot. But not all is lost — the more enhancements you had, the more money you'll get for trading in your robot.

You'll lose your robot enhancements because not all robots have the same enhancements available. For instance, the Katana can have highly-enhanced arms, but its maximum leg enhancements will be lower than its maximum arm enhancements.

On the other hand, the *pilot* training you purchase will apply to every robot.

There are also some special enhancements you can get from *destroying* the secret characters; those will also be lost when you trade in your robot.